# Can't visit hazelcast management center

Tags: java, hazelcast

I'm trying to use Hazelcast management center according this: http://hazelcast.com/products/management-center/

But after I deployed the mancenter-3.3.3.war to my server (Tomcat), there are 2 errors occurred when I tried to start up the server.

```
1. com.hazelcast.management.ManagementCenterService
   WARNING: [172.29.110.114]:5701 [dev] [3.3.3] Read timed out
   java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

2. com.hazelcast.management.ManagementCenterService
   WARNING: [172.29.110.114]:5701 [dev] [3.3.3] http://localhost:80/mancenter/getTask.do?member=172.29.110.114:5701&cluster=dev
   java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://localhost:80/mancenter/getTask.do?member=172.29.110.114:5701&cluster=dev
           at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1623)
           at `enter code here`com.hazelcast.management.ManagementCenterService$TaskPollThread.openTaskInputStream(ManagementCenterService.java:494)
           at com.hazelcast.management.ManagementCenterService$TaskPollThread.processTask(ManagementCenterService.java:433)
           at com.hazelcast.management.ManagementCenterService$TaskPollThread.run(ManagementCenterService.java:414)
```

The second one won't stop printing on the console unless I stopped the server.

Can anyone help with this? I really have no idea what's happening here.

Comment: Are you using port 80 or 8080

Comment: Are you sure that port 80 is the right port? I suppose it should be 8080. Basically you have to state the mancenter url in your hazelcast config file. Maybe there is something wrong.

Comment: Yes, I stated it in hazelcast.xml. The port 80 is what we use for our project.

Comment: I can start it in command line. Like this: java -jar mancenter-*version*.war 8080 mancenter. But it went wrong deploying it in Tomcat server.